# Datatype constraints in multilingual application. SQL Server 2008

Tags: database, sql-server-2008, constraints, multilingual

While developing an ASP.Net application (using SQL server 2008) which has multi language support, what are the data-types that we should not use in the database design?
What problems can arise in a multi-lingual software?

Answer (score 0):

Do not use the char/varchar datatypes. You have to use the nchar/nvarchar datatypes instead to handle the local characters correctly. The only concern/issue is the collation of the fields as this will affect the sort order and comparison of the fields.